# Lists from a list based on specific key

Tags: python, list

Hi I am new in programming. I am having a problem. I don't know what is better solution for this issue. The problem is like this.. I have a list say,

```
list = ['a', '123', '643', 'b', '890', '234', '123', 'd', '432', '678' ]
```

So I want to make 3 lists or a json object, what actually possible please suggest better option. the idea is

```
list_a = ['123', '643']
list_b = ['890', '234', '123']
list_d = ['432', '678']
```

or,

```
list_ob = {"a": ["123", "643"], "b": ["890", "234", "123"], "d": ["432", "678"] }
```

Here a, b, d are only some specific character or can be words. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to reach that, you just need to loop check if it's alpha and then pick up the alpha as `key`. something like the below:

```
In [92]: key = ''
    ...: b = {}
    ...: a = ['a', '123', '643', 'b', '890', '234', '123', 'd', '432', '678' ]
    ...: for i in a:
    ...:   
    ...:     if i.isalpha():
    ...:         b[i]=[]
    ...:         key = i
    ...:     else:
    ...:         b[key].append(i)
In [94]: b
Out[94]: {'a': ['123', '643'], 'b': ['890', '234', '123'], 'd': ['432', '678']}
```

To get your second expect result, just simple do it by:

```
In [95]: b.values()
Out[95]: [['123', '643'], ['890', '234', '123'], ['432', '678']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `collections` module.

**Ex:**

```
import collections
l = ['a', '123', '643', 'b', '890', '234', '123', 'd', '432', '678' ]
res = collections.OrderedDict()
for i in l:
    if i.isalpha():
        res[i] = []
    else:
        res[res.keys()[-1]].append(i)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
OrderedDict([('a', ['123', '643']), ('b', ['890', '234', '123']), ('d', ['432', '678'])])
```

*Or without modules*

```
l = ['a', '123', '643', 'b', '890', '234', '123', 'd', '432', '678', "z", "123" ]
res = {}
key = ""
for i in l:
    if i.isalpha():
        res[i] = []
        key = i
    else:
        res[key].append(i)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This json object you referred to is called `dictionary` in python and in many others programming languages. It is an structure where we have a key and a values associated with it.

In this case it is easier to deal with a dictionary. Let's create an empty dictionary first:

```py
d = dict()
```

Then, you going to create an `for` loop to fill this dictionary:

```py
current_key = ""

for e in l:
    if e.isalpha(): # If is a letter
        current_key = e
        d[current_key] = [] # Create an empty list as value
    else:
        d[current_key].append(e) # Append value
```

Result:

```py
{'a': ['123', '643'], 'b': ['890', '234', '123'], 'd': ['432', '678']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defaultdict seems like good way to go:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def split_list(l):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    current_key = ''
    for el in l:
        if el.isalpha():
            current_key = el
        elif current_key:
            res[current_key].append(el)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
{x[0]:x[1].split() for x in re.findall(r"([a-z])([\s*\d+]*)" , " ".join(list))}
```

> {'a': ['123', '643'], 'b': ['890', '234', '123'], 'd': ['432', '678']}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
l = ['a', '123', '643', 'b', '890', '234', '123', 'd', '432', '678' ]
_t = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x:x.isdigit())]
final_result = {_t[i][0]:_t[i+1] for i in range(0, len(_t), 2)}
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['123', '643'], 'b': ['890', '234', '123'], 'd': ['432', '678']}
```